# How to automatically adjust volume according to the sound around ( mic input ) the player device

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I work in a digital advertising company and I'm working on a project to make the volume automatically increase based on the noise around ( mic input ) and when the sound is not noisy then the volume will return to normal, i'm using lubuntu 20.04.3 OS and my player is electron 9.4.4,have been searching but can't find the solution

Comment: You've not provided any release details; ie. software stack details, which are my usual starting point for questions. I'm not aware of any app, but I'd likely write a script that monitors audio level & adjusts volume based on that if I couldn't find anything.  (`pactl` etc..)

Comment: i'm using standar app  pavucontrol or is there any app that i can use?

Comment: It is very difficult to measure the ambient noise by a microphone on PC or headset. Even you did it correctly, the sound level is not easily determined. For example, the same 70dB in the airplane, library and restaurant, the easiest follow up is in the library. It is not relevant to. You have to do it manually or Boost +20 dB button works better.